# Extract Data to Active Collab Tasks with Tags HTML - PHP

Tags: php, json, api, activecollab

I am trying to pull data from API for active collab, but in the body to the task exist tags HTML, causing a mess in the coding, anybody know what I can do?

My code to push API:

```php
    try {
    function listTasks() {  

        $ch = curl_init();
        $token = 'token';
        curl_setopt_array($ch, [
            CURLOPT_URL => 'https://collab.cadastra.com.br/api/v1/projects/projectnumber/tasks/',

            CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => [
                'X-Angie-AuthApiToken: ' . $token,
                'Content-Type: application/json',
                'x-li-format: json'
            ],
            CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
            CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 30,
            CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "GET",
            CURLOPT_PROTOCOLS => CURLPROTO_HTTPS
        ]);

        $result = curl_exec($ch);
        // $tasks = json_decode($result, true);
        // for ($i = 0; $i < count($tasks); $i++) {
        // if ($tasks[$i]["task_list_id"] == 55979) {
        //         $tasks_name[$i] = $tasks[$i]["name"];
        //     }
        // }

        print_r(filter_var($result, FILTER_SANITIZE_MAGIC_QUOTES));
        curl_close($ch);
        // return $resultado;
    }

    listTasks();
} catch (Error $e) {
    print_r($e->getMessage());
}
// print_r($_POST['email']));
```

This return:

[image]

Comment: I added your image directly to the post. It makes it easier for people to see what it is right away.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use one of PHP function for clean view:

- strip_tags (https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags)
- htmlentities (https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities)

for view the tasks, otherways you must look at the source of request, cause browser is rendering html. if you will have any errors for this, you can the function use for task body.

I hope it help to you. :)

Comment: YEHHH, resolved my problem, but now emerged other problem kkkkkk 

trying transform to var in Array, using json_decode, this var is null :/ 

Can help me to?

Comment: can you type example what you trying to do ?

Comment: i create other ask where I better explain the problem now - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59582393/this-convert-json-in-array-return-is-null