# This Convert JSON in Array return is null

Tags: php, json, api

i need to transform a return JSON in Array, to manipulate the datas, but when trying this array is set as null, i need to use htmlentities why this return in navigator was messed up by the html tags in json.

this is my code:

```
<?php
try {
    function listTasks() {  

        $ch = curl_init();
        $token = 'token';
        curl_setopt_array($ch, [
            CURLOPT_URL => 'https://collab.cadastra.com.br/api/v1/projects/idproject/tasks/',

            CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => [
                'X-Angie-AuthApiToken: ' . $token,
                'Content-Type: application/json',
                'x-li-format: json'
            ],
            CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
            CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 30,
            CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "GET",
            CURLOPT_PROTOCOLS => CURLPROTO_HTTPS
        ]);

        $result = curl_exec($ch);
        $convert = htmlentities($result, ENT_QUOTES, "UTF-8"); // I did this because the return had html tags that gave problems with browser display.
        $tasks = json_decode($convert, true); //this is where I convert to array.
        // for ($i = 0; $i < count($tasks); $i++) {
        // if ($tasks[$i]["task_list_id"] == 55979) {
        //           $tasks_name[$i] = $tasks[$i]["name"];
        //       }
        //   }

        var_dump($tasks); // here it returns null, if I put print_r returns nothing.
        curl_close($ch);
        // return $result;
    }

    listTasks();
} catch (Error $e) {
    print_r($e->getMessage());
}
// print_r($_POST['email']));
```

Someone can help me ?

Comment: What does `var_dump($result);` give?

Comment: I think you meant what var_dump should bring? it should bring a json of array-converted tasks, but it is null.

Comment: I mean the return value from `curl_exec()` so that we can see what is the actual value sent back by the API.

Comment: I think I understand, the browser interprets json, but the var_dump of $convert is a string, so when I try to array it returns me null.

Comment: no, although, what I said doesn't make sense since it's going to be a string, sorry

Comment: `$result` will be a string, it helps understand why the json isn't valid.

Comment: Yeh, $result is a string, but I have some HTML tags on my json's return, so use htmlentities to tweak the browser viewer, if I leave without it, it gets me wrong, and it doesn't show the $ result that later becomes $ convert as a json, however when using or json_decode to transform the array into var $ tasks it assigns a null value :(

Comment: Nigel, You can see the return of curl_exec in this ask here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59580337/extract-data-to-active-collab-tasks-with-tags-html-php

Answer (score 0):

If the cURL request is responding with JSON format, you should first decode it with

```
json_decode
```

and then only use

```
htmlentities
```

for specify array index'es to clear the text. Then you use your way, you make json string invalid, so it can't decode it. anyway you should not use mixed json with html to display it into browser.

Comment: hi, i try, but htmlentities expects a string, if i use json_decode they transform var in array ...

Comment: Try to array map = $convert = array_map("htmlspecialchars", $tasks); but not not work.